# Object vs. Shape angle in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

For some shapes, there are additional properties in the Transform window (e.g. "Line Properties"). One of these properties is Angle. However, the standard object properties already has an Angle property. How are these different? And what is the relevance of the latter when they conflict? How can they come to be conflicting? For example, here is a line which is clearly horizontal, yet the object angle is 2.5 degrees. Can I reset it to 0?

[image]

Comment: what version of AI are you using? I can't recreate results

Comment: @LateralTerminal 2015.3.1. I don't know how to make it happen either.

Comment: Can you recreate this problem if you draw a line in a new document?

Comment: @LateralTerminal No, I tried. If I happen to notice a particular event that causes it I will update the question.

Comment: This is trivial to reproduce in Illustrator 24.0.1.  Just create a line segment, then use the direct selection tool to grab one end and move it somewhere else (to a different angle). The two angle values in the Transform panel are now different.  I am just learning Illustrator, and I assumed that the very basics (lines & paths) would have a clear logic; I find it infuriating that something as simple as this has no explanation that I can find even after hours of hunting around.

Comment: ...But I figured it out. When you move the *anchor point* for a line segment (to adjust the line's angle), Illustrator remembers the original angle of the line, but responds to this action by expanding the bounding box for the path (so that the bounding box is no longer infinitely thin, and so that the adjusted line segment forms the diagonal).  The **Line Property** angle now shows the ACTUAL angle of the visible line on the screen, whereas the **Transform** angle shows the angle of the base of the bounding box.

Answer (score 0):

The two fields are the **same value**. Change one and the other will update to reflect the same change.

It's merely a duplication in the UI. As for why it's duplicated... you'd have to ask Adobe.

To be honest, I have no clue how you go them to be *different* values. However, the option to Align to Pixel Grid at the bottom of the Transform panel would suggest you are using an *older version* of Illustrator. There may have been a bug which was later corrected.

Comment: They aren't quite the same thing, the other is attributes for line objects. This is one of adobes attempt to become svg compatible with illustrator, and i think they are failing horribly. They first need to fix illustrators transformation stack.

Comment: @joojaa all I know is here.. the two fields sync and can never be different values, at least not in AICC2017.

Comment: Try putting in group and rotating that, then change the object.

Comment: Still seems to duplicate @joojaa -- actually it's largely inconsistent. The `<group>` may not have a value in the rotate field even if the objects in the group are rotated. Basically.. looks *really* "buggy" here :) Glad I don't rely on it.

Comment: It is trivial to make the two values be different - see my comment beneath the OP question.